# Angularjs directive with dynamic id will not allow d3 to append

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

I have found an issue where I have an angularJS directive that when I specify an hardcoded ID, it is able to append in the following case, but when it is dynamically formed the append doesn't actually append.  There are no errors thrown by d3 or by the browser, but if you look at the DOM, you will see that the elements were never added. To be clear, the first line does return an object in both cases.

```
var svg = d3.select(id)
svg.append("g")
```

Directive call:

```
<ns-my-directive width="960" height="200" uid="graph{{$index}}" data="d"></ns-my-directive>
```

Directive template:

```
<svg data-ng-attr-id="{{uid}}" class='form-group' width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}"></svg>
```

Directive js:

```
angular.module('myDirective', []).directive('nsMyDirective', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        uid: '@',
        data: '=',
        width: '@',
        height: '@'
    },
    templateUrl:'js/directives/nsMyDirective/ns-my-directive.html',
    controller: function($scope){
        $scope.$watch('data', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            var id = $scope.uid;
            var svg = d3.select(id)
            svg.append("g")

        }       
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem turned out to be that a d3.select() returns an object whether it exists or not.  What the real issue was, is that angular controller code is executed before the template has been filled with variables. The solution is as follows:

```
controller: function($scope, $timeout){
    $timeout(function(){
        var id = $scope.uid;
        var svg = d3.select(id)
        svg.append("g")
    })
})
```